# Powerquery: choosing the right value for a row based on a different table with variable categories

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm not sure this one is even possible as I've been scouring the web for this. I want to add a value to a table (table1) from a different table (table2) based on a value in table1 and variable categories in table2.

So i have 2 tables:
table1- orders

| Order | quantity | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| order1 | 5000 | A |
| order2 | 17000 | B |
| order3 | 1000 | A |
| order4 | 13000 | C |

table2 - priceIDs

| ID | BIN | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1000 | 20 |
| A | 4000 | 15 |
| A | 10000 | 10 |
| B | 5000 | 30 |
| B | 10000 | 20 |
| B | 25000 | 10 |
| B | 50000 | 8 |
| B | 100000 | 5 |
| C | 5000 | 50 |

I want to use the quantity in table1 as a lookup value to see in what "bin" it is situated for that specific ID, so quantitiy 5000 for ID A would have a price of 15 (larger than 4000, smaller than 10000). Final table would look like this:

| Order | quantity | id | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| order1 | 5000 | A | 15 |
| order2 | 17000 | B | 20 |
| order3 | 1000 | A | 20 |
| order4 | 13000 | C | 50 |

anyone had a similar problem in the past and could help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Add a Custom Column to table 1 with:

```
let
  thisId = [id], thisQty = [quantity],
  filterTableId = Table.SelectRows(#"table2 - priceIDs", each [ID] = thisId),
  maxBinRow = Table.Max(filterTableId, "BIN", [price = null]),
  filterMaxBinRow = Table.Max(Table.SelectRows(filterTableId, each [BIN] <= thisQty), "BIN", maxBinRow),
  price = filterMaxBinRow[price]
in
  price
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution adds a custom column in a similar way to Sam Nseir. It does also rely on BIN column being sorted ascending as shown:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Orders"]}[Content],

// Add a new column called price
AddPriceColumn = Table.AddColumn(Source, "price", 
    each 
        let
    // for each row of the Orders table define parameters "id" (equal to the id in current row), "quantity" (equal to quantity in current row) and
    // "index" (for each row of Orders, number of rows in the filteredPricetable defined later)  
        id = [id], quantity = [quantity], index = Table.RowCount(filteredPriceTbl) - 1,

    // for each row of the Orders table, filter the PriceIDs table based on the id being the same as the id in the current row of Orders table 
    // and the BIN column of the PriceIDs table being less than or equal to the current row quantity
        filteredPriceTbl = Table.SelectRows(PriceIDs, each [ID] = id and [BIN] <= quantity), 

    // then, using the index variable find the CorrectPrice by navigating the price column in the nested filteredPriceTbl for the number of rows equal to "index" 
    // have deducted 1 in definition of "index" to accommodate PQ being zero based.
        CorrectPrice = try filteredPriceTbl[price]{ index } otherwise null
        in
        
        CorrectPrice
    )
in
AddPriceColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method. You'll have to test to see which is better for your data:

- Match the ID's by doing a `Table.NestedJoin`
- Then select the appropriate price
- ***Assumes `BIN` in the `PriceIDs` table are sorted ascending as you show. If not you will need to add a `Table.Sort` step***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="PriceIDs"]}[Content],
    PriceIDs = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", type text}, {"BIN", Int64.Type}, {"price", Currency.Type}}),

    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Orders"]}[Content],
    Orders = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{
        {"Order", type text},{"quantity", Int64.Type},{"id", type text}}),

    #"Merge Tables" = Table.NestedJoin(Orders,"id",PriceIDs,"ID","merge", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Add Price column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Merge Tables","price", (r)=>
        Table.Last(Table.SelectRows(r[merge], each [BIN] <= r[quantity]))[price], Currency.Type),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Add Price column",{"merge"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

***Orders***
[image]

***PriceIDs***
[image]

***Result***
[image]